# Lucene Index converting gen0 memory to unmanaged resource

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, dotmemory

I am using Lucene NET v4.8 beta, and I have noticed that my service consume more and more memory whenever I add huge amounts of data to the index.

I analyzed this through dotMemory, seen below.  The spike of memory at minute 4 is when I added a bunch of data to the Index.  I understand the increase in gen0 memory because I am creating `IndexWriter` object and performing write/commit operations.  However, it seems as if, once the GC is called, the `gen0` objects it collects becomes part of `unmanaged memory` instead (for example, at minute 5:30 in the screenshot, we can see that `gen0` memory usage got collected, but `total memory` remained the same - `unmanaged memory` grew the same amount that `gen0` memory got collected).

[image: dotMemory analysis]

[image: dotMemory analysis]

I have already implemented the Dispose pattern in my code properly for `IndexWriter` and `IndexReader`, but this issue remains.  The only 'fix' I was able to do I was able to do was forcing Garbage Collect to collect, via `GC.Collect()` manually in the code, but it still doesn't remove all the extra unmanaged memory.

My questions are, what is causing Lucene NET to behave like this (turning gen0 objects into unmanaged resources)? And is there a way to fix this without having to do `GC.Collect()` every so often?

Comment: `IndexReader` uses a `ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>` to track segments without holding a strong reference to them. Unfortunately, it calls into unmanaged code and has no `Dispose()` method. The situation is a bit worse on .NET Framework/.NET Standard 2.0 because there is no enumerator, which is something we need to do in several places, so in 4.8.0-beta00016 it was changed from a poorly implemented `WeakDictionary` to `ConditionalWeakTable` with weak events to enumerate the keys. Are you on .NET Framework on a version prior to 4.8.0-beta00016?

Comment: Hi NightOwl, thanks again for your response! I am currently on .NET 3.1.

Comment: "I have already implemented the Dispose pattern in my code properly for `IndexWriter` and `IndexReader`" - One thing to note is that it is usually best to use a singleton with `IndexWriter` or `IndexReader` rather than opening one per request. This is best accomplished by using a DI container that will call dispose when the application shuts down. If you use both in the same application, you can keep `IndexWriter` open and then call `IndexWriter.GetReader()` for each request. I don't know if that could be the cause of this particular problem and it is possible this is a bug.

Comment: I suggest reporting this [on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/issues). Please include a *runnable* piece of code so we can to reproduce the behavior (it doesn't have to be real data).